# Modal pop up in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I am using MVC3, C# engine

My question : I am checking from my controller if there is an Active batch and if there is not then display the result. But if there is a Active batch need to display a modal pop up alert

```
if (!CheckActiveStatus())
        {
            GetAllErrors(batchID);
        }
        else
        { 
            // Need to show modal alert box here
        }
        return View();
```

Should I create a partial view and call that page. ?
I checked few articles but unable to understand how to implement. Any help is appreicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is **server-side** code.  It is not possible to show a dialog box on your client from server-side code.

What you need to do is have your controller "tell" the view to show the dialog box.

Model:

```
class MyModel
{
  public bool IsShowAlert { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var model = new MyModel()
{
  IsShowAlert = false;
};

if (!CheckActiveStatus())
{
  GetAllErrors(batchID);
}
else
{ 
  // Need to show modal alert box here
  model.IsShowAlert = true;
}
return View(model);
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.MyModel

@* .... *@

@if (Model.IsShowAlert) 
{
  // Do what you need to to show the alert
}
```